# Using Computed Field in LightSwitch Query

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

Lets say I have a simple table of Customer with Field `DayOfBirth` and a computed field 'Age'
Now I want to Search the table using Age.

I pass Age as parameter to the query so the first thing that came to my mind was :

```
                    query = from c in query
                    where (DateTime.Now - c.DateOfBirth).Days / 360 == Age.Value
                    select c;
```

but this of course wont work as the data provider wouldn't know how to execute ".Days"

so what is the proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be adding non-Computed field inside the table and on adding new records event I just Compute the age and save it with the database so I can search by it later !

but I`m sure there should be better idea !

Comment: No, I believe that this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways of getting around the *.Days* part, but you'll have the same problem with the *Age*, property, except there won't be a way around that one. Computed properties only exist in LightSwitch itself, so once again the data provider isn't going to be able to use them.

Stacker's suggestion of adding a *non-computed property* & storing the calculated value *in the database* is the way I would do it (if I wasn't using a *RIA Service*, which is the way I actually handle these situations).